# How can I find week numbers with weeks starting on Sunday in Python?

Tags: python, datetime

Total newbie to Python, so apologies in advance if this is obvious. I have a number of datetime values, for which I would like to identify a year and week number, for example:

```
start_date = datetime.datetime(2015,1,26,0,0,0)
```

The catch is, I would like the week to be defined as starting on a Sunday.

I understand that the datetime.isocalendar() can get me week numbers, but they will be calculated under the assumption that weeks start on Mondays. Is there any other way?

Edit: Running Python 2.7.6

Thank you!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to determine the first day of week in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4265697/how-to-determine-the-first-day-of-week-in-python)

Comment: To be clear, I'm not trying to figure out the first day of the week, I'm trying to figure out the week number. Those are two very different problems.

Comment: What have you tried? Which version of python? Have you looked at `date.isocalendar`. I called up the docs for datetime and searched for 'week number'

Comment: Yes, @kdopen: as I explained above, isocalendar defines weeks as starting with Mondays, not Sundays. I need the week to be defined as running Sunday through end of Saturday.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

String format `%U` will give the week of the year counting from Sunday:

```
t1 = datetime.datetime.now()
t1.strftime("%U")
```

See http://strftime.org/ for full list of format parameters.

Comment: unfortunately this method isn't link with iso standard, eg.              
 pd.to_datetime('2021-01-01').week, int(pd.to_datetime('2021-01-01').strftime("%U"))      In years where is 53. week it return 0 for first week not 1

Answer (score -1):

you can just do +1 to the date you're working with and the isocalendar()[1] will work :)