# PHP DateTime() class, change first day of the week to Monday

Tags: php, class, datetime

The DateTime class in PHP (5.3+) works just great as long as the first day of the week in your country is Sunday. In the Netherlands the first day of the week is Monday and that just makes the class useless for building a calendar with week view and calculations.

I can't seem to find an answer on Stackoverflow or the rest of the Internet on how to have DateTime act as if the first day of the week is Monday.

I found this piece on Stackoverflow, but it doesn't fix all the ways you can get into trouble and it's not an elegant solution.

```
$dateTime = new DateTime('2012-05-14');
$monday = clone $dateTime->modify(('Sunday' == $dateTime->format('l')) ? 'Monday last week' : 'Monday this week');
```

Is there a way to change this or extent DateTime? Can't imagine it's not a setting as most of Europe starts their weeks on monday.

**Added:**
Posting the full calendar and functions code will not make things clearer. But here is one one line for example.
I often have to check what the first day of the week is or  calculate from the first day of the week to a different date and time in that week. My code is getting full of these:

```
$startOfWeek = $date->modify(('Sunday' == $date->format('l')) ? 'Monday last week' : 'Monday this week')->modify('+3 hours')->format(DATETIME);
```

I also get an unwanted result trying to get the first full week of the month or year. As my $date object doesn't always contain the same date I have to keep checking it this way, making the code difficult to read. Having a lot more programming to do on this calendar I can't forsee where it's going to bug again.

**EDIT** There are some inconsistencies though. For some strange reason DateTime does get this next one right:

```
$test = new DateTime('2012-10-29'); // Monday
echo $test->modify('Sunday this week')->format('Y-m-d');  // 2012-11-04

// But...

$test = new DateTime('2012-11-04'); // Sunday
echo $test->modify('Monday this week')->format('Y-m-d');  // 2012-11-05 instead of 2012-10-29
```

But I think I can make the question clearer:
**Can the DateTime() class be used with monday as the first day of the week. If not, can the class be extended to use monday as the first day of the week.**

**UPDATE:**
Ok, I think I'm getting somewhere... I'm not a pro at coding classes..but this seems to work for the weeks. But it still needs rules for first day, second day... and also for the day name Sunday itself. I don't think this is foolproof. I would appreciate any help to fix it.

```
class EuroDateTime extends DateTime {

// Fields
private $weekModifiers = array (
    'this week',
    'next week',
    'previous week',
    'last week'
);

// Override "modify()"
public function modify($string) {

    // Search pattern
    $pattern = '/'.implode('|', $this->weekModifiers).'/';

    // Change the modifier string if needed
    if ( $this->format('N') == 7 ) { // It's Sunday
        $matches = array();
        if ( preg_match( $pattern, $string, $matches )) {
            $string = str_replace($matches[0], '-7 days '.$matches[0], $string);
        }
    }
    return parent::modify($string);

}

}
// This works
$test = new EuroDateTime('2012-11-04');
echo $test->modify('Monday this week')->format('Y-m-d');
// And I can still concatenate calls like the DateTime class was intended
echo $test->modify('Monday this week')->modify('+3 days')->format('Y-m-d');
```

Comment: What's the problem you are facing exactly?

Comment: Sounds like an XY problem. The fact that Sunday is mapped to 0 shouldn't stop you from using a different technique to determine the beginning of the weeks as any other day.

Comment: Your question is abstract. Provide code that you use to create calendar. As for now there are no answer for your question

Comment: I don't see the problem; `echo $dateTime->format( 'N' );` will give you the ["ISO-8601 numeric representation of the day of the week"](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php#refsect1-function.date-parameters) (that starts with Monday) ranging from `1` through `7`. Just subtract `1` to get a zero-indexed representation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found this to work, yet there are some inconsistencies in PHP's DateTime class.

If the departing date is a sunday the previous monday is not considered the same week (fixed by this class). But departing from a monday, the next sunday is considered as the same week. If they fix that in the future this class will need some additions.

```
class EuroDateTime extends DateTime {

// Override "modify()"
public function modify($string) {

    // Change the modifier string if needed
    if ( $this->format('N') == 7 ) { // It's Sunday and we're calculating a day using relative weeks
        $matches = array();
        $pattern = '/this week|next week|previous week|last week/i';
        if ( preg_match( $pattern, $string, $matches )) {
            $string = str_replace($matches[0], '-7 days '.$matches[0], $string);
        }
    }
    return parent::modify($string);

}

}
```

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing to stop you manually modifying a date to get the "first" day of the week, depending on your definition of "first". For instance:

```
$firstDayOfWeek = 1; // Monday
$dateTime = new DateTime('2012-05-16'); // Wednesday

// calculate how many days to remove to get back to the "first" day
$difference = ($firstDayOfWeek - $dateTime->format('N'));
if ($difference > 0) { $difference -= 7; }
$dateTime->modify("$difference days");

var_dump($dateTime->format('r')); // "Mon, 14 May 2012 00:00:00 +0000"
```

Notice how the output changes as you vary `$firstDayOfWeek`; if it was changed to `4` above (Thursday), it would then consider `Thu, 10 May 2012` as the "first" day.

**Edit**: this is a rather basic example. The correct way to do this is by using the user/system's locale to give you the "first" day, and compute from there. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/727471/how-do-i-get-the-first-day-of-the-week-for-the-current-locale-php-l8n) for more information.

Comment: Thanks cbuckley, does this mean that the DateTime class itself cannot be set to use monday as the first weekday natively?

Comment: For anything smarter, the correct way to do it would be using the locale. I've added an update to that effect.

Comment: cbuckly, I don't think the locale update got through. I'm trying to write a class now based on your example that will intercept anything that goes like 'next week', 'this week', 'last week' and changes it. Dunno if i'm just wasting my time..

Answer (score 0):

I too am confused about what the problem is, because `DateTime` *does* have a notion of the week starting from Monday: The [`N` format](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php#refsect1-function.date-parameters) gives you the days of the week counting from Monday to Sunday, with Monday being 1 and Sunday being 7. Moreover, the `W` format, the only way to get a week number, also starts the week on Monday. (I seem to remember that Dutch week numbers aren't exactly like ISO week numbers, but that's a different story). So what feature are you missing exactly?

**Edit** So the problem is (only?) that the [relative datetime formats](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php), such as "Monday this week" give the wrong result when the reference date is a Sunday. From the docs it sounds like `DateTime` just defers to `strtotime`, which is supposed to be locale-dependent. So **if** you have your locale set properly and this is not working, it sounds like a bug (for what that's worth).

Comment: Try this:$test = new DateTime('2012-11-04');
echo $test->modify('Monday this week')->format('Y-m-d'); // 2012-11-05
// I expect to get 2012-10-29

Comment: I see; so the English specifications for relative offsets don't come in a Monday-first variant.

Comment: Exactly ....sucks for the all the countries that consider Monday the first day of the week. And I just found out the PHP DateTime extension was written by a Dutch guy.... #WayToGoDerickRethans

Answer (score 0):

You can also get the start and the end of the week with setISODate, the last parameter is the ISO-daynumber in the week, monday is 1 and sunday 7

```
$firstday = new \DateTime();
$lastday = clone($firstday);
$firstday->setISODate($firstday->format("Y"), $firstday->format("W"), 1);
$lastday->setISODate($lastday->format("Y"), $lastday->format("W"), 7);
```

Comment: What is your expectation for the value of `$lastDay` if `$firstDay` is set to `2024-01-27`? The value of `7` is confusing; is it the previous or next Sunday?

Comment: @Anthony I would expect `firstdate: Mon 2024-01-22, lastdate: Sun 2024-01-28`  ... and thats actually the result of the code above :) ;-)

Comment: Smiley faces are so juvenile and passive aggressive. Regardless, [this](https://onlinephp.io/c/0638e) is the issue that you have failed to understand. The behavior is very unexpected.

Comment: @Anthony :) luckily i directly see what you did wrong in your example, the issue is that you keep using $day0 to set the isodate for day6,7 and so on, see here the correct usuage https://onlinephp.io/c/5db04 with the results assumed by  me :)

Comment: I structured the example to show a specific issue that your answer also unwittingly demonstrates. The behavior of this function is not consistent with other PHP date functions, _and_ the behavior is unintuitive. In case it isn't clear, this discussion is about a problem with PHP, not your interpretation of the output. Your answer needs to include caveats for bad behavior that is well documented in the PHP documentation. Case in point, using values beyond 1-7 should result in deterministic answers, but that isn't what happens. That's a major issue.

Answer (score 0):

The proper answer:

```
$week_start_day; // 0 - Sunday, 1 - Monday

$date_time_from = new DateTime('now');
$date_time_to = clone $date_time_from;

$this_week_first_day = $date_time_from->setISODate($date_time_from->format("Y"), $date_time_from->format("W"), $week_start_day);
$this_week_last_day = $date_time_to->setISODate($date_time_to->format("Y"), $date_time_to->format("W"), (6 + $week_start_day));
```

Comment: Can you explain what's happening here please.  Does this actually change the way PHP calculates dates that depend on the first day of the week?  For example, if I run your code and then execute date("oW", strtotime($today)) will it consider Monday a different week than the Sunday before it?

Comment: @Vincent DateTime is an object that returns values, based on the input you pass to it. So you create two objects, one for first day and one for last day. And you get results by running some methods. Pretty straight forward. This does not change 'the way PHP calculates dates'. It just creates object(s) with the goal to get date from them. They are isolated, like all objects are.

Comment: This answer makes the most sense to me, but the explanation really needs to be in the answer itself instead of a comment. The output is not what one would expect, so more details are necessary. For example, running your code with `$week_start_day = 0` with 2024-01-26 as the value of `$date_time_from` yields 2024-01-21 for the first day and 2024-01-20 for the last day. The value for last_day should have been 2024-01-27. `setISODate` needs 1 to be Monday and 7 to be Sunday, which is part of the problem.

Comment: I added an answer to provide more details about how this answer can be confusing.

Answer (score -1):

Some of the other answers mention using `setISODate`, which works, but you need to take into account the unintuitive behaviors.

```
<?php

// A Monday 
$anchor = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', '2024-01-29');

$day0 = clone($anchor);
$day1 = clone($anchor);
$day6 = clone($anchor);
$day7 = clone($anchor);
$day8 = clone($anchor);

$day0->setISODate($day0->format("Y"),$day0->format("W"),0);
$day1->setISODate($day0->format("Y"),$day0->format("W"),1);
$day6->setISODate($day0->format("Y"),$day0->format("W"),6);
$day7->setISODate($day0->format("Y"),$day0->format("W"),7);
$day8->setISODate($day0->format("Y"),$day0->format("W"),8);

echo $day0->format("Y-m-d") . "\n";
echo $day1->format("Y-m-d") . "\n";
echo $day6->format("Y-m-d") . "\n";
echo $day7->format("Y-m-d") . "\n";
echo $day8->format("Y-m-d") . "\n";
```

Output:

```
2024-01-28
2024-01-22
2024-01-27
2024-01-28
2024-01-29
```

Use [this](https://onlinephp.io/c/0638e) link to run the code.

`setISODate` ([documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.setisodate.php) and [related documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetimeimmutable.setisodate.php)) uses 1 for Monday and 7 for Sunday, which is confusing when you compare it to other datetime functions that use 0 for Sunday instead of 7. Using values other than 1 through 7 produces weird behaviors even though the function is supposed to 'wrap' in an intuitive way. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45745698/setisodate-work-that-way) is a similar question with more information in the comments and answers.

Comment: The problem here is that you set `$day0` to day `0` (weekstart on Sunday) so that `->format('W')` (ISO 8601 week starts on monday) will print out the previous weeknumber, so when you keep use this number now to set the next isodates the dates will not match your expectation, e.g they refer to "last week" :-) this can get tricky for the change of the year but with the dates in your example here it does not matter at all, just dont keep using `$day0` then to setISODate to the other days.. see working usuage here:  https://onlinephp.io/c/5db04

Comment: Still you made a good point here, i also think that it is unintuitive and would discourage the usuage without knowing the implications especially on year change, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date

Comment: There is not an issue with my example. `day0` was chosen on purpose because the integer value for dayOfWeek is meant to be beyond the prescribed range (1-7). The documentation says it should work differently than how it actually works. The point is to anchor the calculation on one week, and then pass different values for dayOfWeek to see how it behaves, especially because some applications expect 0 to be Sunday.

Comment: Doesn´t the [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.setisodate.php) clearly say that the dayOfTheWeek argument is the `offset` relative to the start of the week on index 1, it does not say it must be in range 1-7, you could also use `-25` or `365` as argument for that and it would set the datetime correctly. Or what am I missing here?