# PHP DateTime 'first monday of the week' returns following week's Monday

Tags: php, datetime

Attempting to get the first Monday of the first Week of the month.
May 1st is a Sunday therefore the previous Monday is expected to be the first Monday.

```
$date = '2016-05-01';

$dateTimeObject = new DateTime($date, new DateTimeZone('Europe/London'));
$dateTimeObject->modify('first monday of this week');
echo $dateTimeObject->format('d');
```

However this echos 02 which is the following week's Monday when it should be April 25?

Comment: Sunday would be the beginning of the week, so the first monday would be 2.

Comment: Is it possible to set Monday as beginning of the week?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP DateTime() class, change first day of the week to Monday](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13128854/php-datetime-class-change-first-day-of-the-week-to-monday)