# setISODate work that way?

Tags: php, php-7, isodate

**I am testing these cases:**

```
$date = new \DateTime();
echo($date->format('Y.m.d')) . PHP_EOL;

$date->setISODate(2018, 1, 1);
echo($date->format('Y.m.d')) . PHP_EOL;

$date->setISODate(2019, 1, 1);
echo($date->format('Y.m.d')) . PHP_EOL;

$date->setISODate(2020, 1, 1);
echo($date->format('Y.m.d')) . PHP_EOL;
```

**Ouput:**

```
2017.08.17
2018.01.01
2018.12.31
2019.12.30
```

**I understood that it would show this:**

```
2017.08.17
2018.01.01
2019.01.01
2020.01.01
```

Why does that happen?

Surely there is something I did not quite understand.

Comment: You know that the second argument is a week number, not the month, right?

Comment: check the docs bro and the examples. http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.setisodate.php

Comment: Are you sure you want [`DateTime::setISODate()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.setisodate.php)? Its second argument is the week number, not the month. From your expectations I think in fact you are looking for [`DateTime::setDate()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.setdate.php).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The arguments are `year`, `week`, `dayofweek`. PHP's week starts on Monday, and week 1 of a year is the first week that has at least 4 days in January.

In 2018, the year starts on Monday, so week 1 starts on January 1, and that's day 1 of the week.

In 2019, the year starts on Tuesday, so week 1 starts on Monday, December 31, 2018, and that's day 1 of the week.

In 2020, the year starts on Wednesday, so week 1 starts on Monday, December 30, 2019, so that's day 1 of the week.

Comment: thanks for you complet explication. I did not consider the beginning of the week that way.

Answer (score 1):

there is another problem with setISODate() especially visible for 1st week of 2021 (1.1.2021 - 3.1.2021).

ISO says it is a week #53, but once you do setISODate(2021, 53) you get year 2022